# AutoComplete jquery display only name string from Objects

Tags: jquery, autocomplete

I am working on an auto complete jquery textbox that talks to a API that returns a list of objects but I only have to suggest the list of names from the objects

```
$(function() {

$( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
             source: "http://localhost:8181/jquery/api/country?term="
            });
});
```

How to I get only the names in my script with out changing the API, API returns objects as a json

---

I tried something like this :

```
 $(function() {  
   $("#tags").autocomplete(  
   {  
       source : function(request, response) {  
           $.ajax({  
               url : "http://localhost:8181/jquery/api/state/regex",  
               dataType : "json",  
               data : {  
                   term : request.term  
               },  
               success : function(data) {  
               var out = $.parseJSON(data);

                   response($.each(out, function(i, item) {    //ITEM HERE IS UNDEFINED!!!!!

                       return {  

                           label: item.stateName,  
                           value: item.stateName  
                       };  
                   }));  
               },  
               error: function(error) {  
                alert("hi");  
               }   
           });  

       },  
       minLength : 1  
   });
```

});

but it never goes into the success function

Comment: Your source should point to a file that returns a list of objects. What is the code in your source file?

Comment: Please note the version of Autocomplete (plugin, jQuery UI, and the version/source if it is a plugin) as there are several and the api differs

Comment: Can I not wire source to a REST end point that return Json? thats what I am trying to do

Comment: I am still stuck with this, can anyone pls help?

Comment: So are you getting the error alert every time? check the Network Tab on Chrome Dev Tools or similar to analyze the ajax call response